# How to adjust NSStackView to full height of subviews

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsstackview

I have the following Swift script:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import AppKit
import Foundation

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)  // Magic to accept keyboard input and be docked!

struct DialogError: Error, LocalizedError {
  let errorDescription: String?

  init(_ description: String) {
    errorDescription = description
  }
}

struct Settings {
  var title: String
  var text: String
  var okButton: String
  var cancelButton: String

  var width: Int?
  var height: Int?
}

struct ListOptions {
  var options = [String]()
  var defaultOption = 0
  var multiple = false
}

class TableViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

  var initialized = false
  var frame = NSRect()
  var opts = ListOptions()
  var defaultOption = 0
  var tableView = NSTableView()

  convenience init(frame: NSRect, options: ListOptions) {
    self.init()
    self.frame = frame
    self.opts = options
    self.tableView = NSTableView(frame: frame)
    self.view = self.tableView
  }

  override func viewDidLayout() {
    if !initialized {
      initialized = true
      setupTableView()
    }
  }

  func setupTableView() {
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.headerView = nil
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = self.opts.multiple
    self.tableView.usesAutomaticRowHeights = true
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
    self.tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableView.SelectionHighlightStyle.regular
    self.tableView.selectRowIndexes(
      IndexSet(integer: self.opts.defaultOption), byExtendingSelection: false)
    //tableView!.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.vibrantDark)

    let col = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "col"))
    col.minWidth = 200
    tableView.addTableColumn(col)
  }

  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return self.opts.options.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
    -> NSView?
  {
    let text = NSTextField()
    text.stringValue = self.opts.options[row]
    text.isEditable = false
    text.drawsBackground = false
    text.isBordered = false
    let cell = NSTableCellView()
    cell.addSubview(text)

    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.addConstraint(
      NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: text, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    cell.addConstraint(
      NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: text, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .left,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    cell.addConstraint(
      NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: text, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .right,
        multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
    let rowView = NSTableRowView()
    rowView.isEmphasized = true
    return rowView
  }
}

func makeDefaultAlert(_ settings: Settings, listOpts: ListOptions) -> (NSAlert, TableViewController)  {
  let a = NSAlert()
  a.messageText = settings.title
  a.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.informational
  a.addButton(withTitle: settings.okButton)
  a.addButton(withTitle: settings.cancelButton)

  a.buttons[0].keyEquivalent = "\r"
  a.buttons[1].keyEquivalent = "\u{1b}"

  // Text as accessory view since
  // Height can not be changed
  let v = NSStackView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: settings.width ?? 250, height: 350))
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------** This is a problem HERE. I dont know the height...

  v.orientation = NSUserInterfaceLayoutOrientation.vertical
  v.distribution = NSStackView.Distribution.equalSpacing
  v.spacing = 10

  // Text 1
  let text = NSTextField(wrappingLabelWithString: settings.text)
  text.isEditable = false
  text.drawsBackground = true
  v.addView(text, in: NSStackView.Gravity.center)

  // Text 2
  let text2 = NSTextField(wrappingLabelWithString: settings.text)
  text2.isEditable = false
  text2.drawsBackground = true
  v.addView(text2, in: NSStackView.Gravity.center)

  //Table
  let scrollView = NSScrollView(
    frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: settings.width ?? 250, height: 100))
  scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
  scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
  let clipView = NSClipView(frame: scrollView.bounds)
  clipView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
  let con = TableViewController(frame: clipView.bounds, options: listOpts)
  con.tableView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
  clipView.documentView = con.tableView
  scrollView.contentView = clipView
  v.addView(scrollView, in: NSStackView.Gravity.center)

  a.accessoryView = v

  return (a, con)
}

func runOptionsDialog() throws {

  let text = """
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
    et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    """

  let listOpts = ListOptions(options: ["option1", "option2"], multiple: true)
  let settings = Settings(title: "Title", text: text, okButton: "Ok", cancelButton: "Cancel")

  let a = makeDefaultAlert(settings, listOpts: listOpts)
  let alert = a.0
  app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
  alert.runModal()
}

try runOptionsDialog()
```

When running `swift script.swift` this creates succesfully the following alert:

[image: Alert]

The scrolling is perfect, but I want that the whole `NSStackView`  in `makeDefaultAlert(...)` scales to the complete height of the subviews, without having to give it a `height: 500` such that everything fits perfectly. How can we automatically adjust a parent view depending on its subviews, here 2 `NSTextField`s and 1 `NSScrollView` (table). I am having a hard time to understand if I need some constraints or something like that, which I have no clue how to setup programatically?

Comment: A scroll view scrolls and doesn't adjust to its content. Why don't you put the texts in a stack view instead of a table view?

Comment: The text are in a stackview, below the 2 texts is a table (option 1, option 2) which is clipped because the StackView size is only 350, thats the problem

Comment: Have you tried `setClippingResistancePriority(_:for:)`?

Comment: That did not have an effect. I think the initial with of 350px is the one which it tries to keep, I would have liked that the NSStackview really is as big as its content... Do I need to layout it first somehow??

Comment: Do you want full "witdth", "with" or "height" of the subviews? I'm confused.

Comment: I want full height of all subviews.